# VBA Excel: How to read certain parts of variable length in a cell

Tags: database, vba, excel

So, programming beginner here.

I need to extract some information from a database. Namely, i need the "description" corresponding to each ID that is given to each log in the database.
The database gives me the data i need like this:
An excel worksheet where for each ID in the database, it fills a cell in the first column  with the corresponding data.

It looks like this (the stuff in brackets isn't actually part of the data):

```
(Cell A1:) ID, "Project>Project Name","Date","Duration","Person",(....),"Description","Date Updated", (and so on)

(Cell A2:) 12345, "VBAEXCELSTACKOVERFLOW123","2016-03-24","8hrs","j doe",(...),"finding a way to extract this sentence","2016-03-24 10:05:43", (and so on)

(Cell A3:) 12346, "VBAEXCELSTACKOVERFLOW123","2016-03-24","6hrs","w smith",(...),"i need this one too","2016-03-24 10:06:20", (and so on)

(Cell A4:) (....)
```

I need to get the description part of each cell and save it in a way, where it still corresponds to the ID, so that i can paste it into another spreadsheet, in which only the IDs are given.

I think the biggest clue is that the description part is always the nth object in the cell. It always goes: ID, "...","...","...","description","..." .
The only thing, that is variable, is the actual content in the parentheses.

So what I want to do is make an array or a dictionary (or the VBA equivalent), that saves the ID corresponding to "the 5th entry in parentheses in cell Ax".

I don't expect a foolproof code from you. I just need some kind of tip where to start, as i'm kind of lost. The only thing google gave me was people who just counted the words in a cell. But that certainly doesn't solve my problem.

Huge thank you in advance

Comment: How do you get the database data in there? Did you import a file? Is it a direct link via ODBC? It is important to first check if you cannot get the data in a better format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use split(range("a1").value,","), this will give you and array of the line using the comma as delimiter, then the id will be in index 0 and then you can determine what you want, from the example, you'd add index 0 as your key and index 4

something like (not tested)

```
dim strSplit() as string
dim dicIDSandDesc as new scripting.dictionary

strSplit=split(range("a1").value,",")
dicIDSandDesc.add strSplit(0),strSplit(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Split_String()
    Dim WordArr() As String
    Dim txt As String
    CurrSheetRowCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To CurrSheetRowCount
        txt = Cells(i, 1).Value
        WordArr() = Split(txt, ",")
        Cells(i, 2).Value = WordArr(1)     'here 2 is the column number where id will be displyed
        Cells(i, 3).Value = WordArr(6)     'here 3 is the column number where description will be displyed
    Next i
End Sub
```